# Which scope should I use for a personal access token meant only to add ssh keys to my GitHub account?

Tags: github-api, github-oauth

I want to be able to add ssh keys to my GitHub account from a bash script (using `curl`).

The documentation points that the best way to authenticate is by using a [personal access token](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens).

Following [the steps to create a token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), I need to specify which scopes it will give me access too.
In respect of the "principle of least privilege", I would like it to permit only to add new ssh keys (write).

However, I am not sure which category this fall under. I looked at the [documentation of scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/), but could not find any reference to "ssh keys".

Which scope(s) should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section `admin:public_key` is what I was looking for.

In particular the scope `write:public_key`.